# Cruise control.NET to ignore changes in some local folders?

Tags: .net, scripting

Thanks for the great help u had done .Infact i was now able to detect modifications in my local folder itself.But now i face another bottleneck.

When my cruise control.NET detect any modifications in my source files it starts building and it checks by polling every 60 seconds.

Now the results of the build files are getting populated in my folder itself,so the cruise control.NET sees the modification and starts the build again and again and it becomes a chain process.

So is there anyway where i can keep some check on the cruise control.NET looking only for modifications for some folders and jst filtering out some other things.

eg:If i am looking out for folder named build which has 5 folders namely A,B,C,D,RESULTS.

I just need to look out for modifications for folders A,B,C and D and not the RESULTS as the RESULTS folder contain files which are the end product of my building process.

I hope i am able to communicate my problem effectively.

Thanks and regards
Maddy

Answer (score 0):

Try the filtered source control block: http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Filtered+Source+Control+Block

Comment: Hi,But this one just include or excludes files based on patterns.But what way can i exlude a whole folder as such.
Thanks
Maddy

Comment: Did you read the section on PathFilters: ** is a folder wild card.

Comment: This is what i kept:
  <exclusionFilters>
     <pathFilter>
      <pattern>C:\MySource\temp\**</pattern>
     </pathFilter>
    </exclusionFilters>
I am jst getting error which says that unused node detected ie <exclusion filters>
Is der anyting wrong in this code??
Thanks
Maddy

Comment: <sourcecontrol type="filtered"> ?